# Is it possible to run AWS Athena on an S3 that has files from two different formats?

Tags: amazon-athena

I have an S3 that has a long list of files in two different formats!
CSV files that contain the word "log" have 10 columns, and CSV files that contain the word "sever" have 20 columns (The variables are also different)

Is it possible to run with Athena on S3 and query only the "log" files? and if so, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

No, Athena will read all files in the table's (or each partition's) `LOCATION`. There is no way to configure it to read only some files.

Comment: So what do you suggest to do in this case? how to use Athena on this S3? What else can I do?

Comment: Querying using WHERE clause on the filename (accessed by "$path") can solve this issue?

Comment: There are workarounds, like using `$path` and `SymlinkTextInputFormat`, but nothing that will be very clean.